# pip installing Azure cli is taking forever. How can i speed this up?

Tags: python, azure-cli, requirements.txt

Got the following requirements.txt which i am pip installing. azure-cli is taking forever, longer then 7 min just to install. how can i speed this up?

```
azureml-train-core==1.47.0
azureml-sdk==1.47.0
azure-storage-blob==12.13.1
matplotlib==3.6.1
numpy==1.23.4
pandas== 1.5.1
pathlib==1.0.1
python-dotenv==0.14.0
pytz==2020.4
azure-cli== 2.42.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since azure-cli has a lot of dependent packages , nearly 40 so the download will take a huge time to download.

Steps to improve :

1. Using poetry packaged .whl file , wheel installation are faster.
2. Having a high speed internet connection.
3. Upgrade your pip to latest version.
4. pip --disable-pip-version-check install , to prevent checking pip version.